# changing parent element if one of the children nodes has certain context using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform

I have got the following XML:

```
<vce>
<document url="https://amdocssandbox.service-now.com/aps/? 
table=sn_customerservice_aps_and_optima_cases&sys_id=300384- 
040406&id=aps_case_details" vse-key-normalized="vse-key-normalized">
<content name="Knowledge_Item_type" type="text">Case</content>
<content name="Knowledge_item_ID" type="text" name-original="Case_ID">300384- 
040406</content>
<content name="PSP_update_dt" type="text" name- 
original="PSP_Case_update_dt">1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000</content>
<content name="Item_URL_internal" type="text" name- 
original="Case_URL_internal">
https://amdocssandbox.service-now.com/aps/? 
table=sn_customerservice_aps_and_optima_cases&sys_id=300384- 
040406&id=aps_case_details
</content>
<content name="Item_URL_external" type="text" name- 
original="Case_URL_external">
https://amdocssandbox.service-now.com/aps/? 
table=sn_customerservice_aps_and_optima_cases&sys_id=300384- 
040406&id=aps_case_details
</content>
<content name="Product_tree" type="text">^ > ^ > ^ > ^</content>
<content name="User_type" type="text" action="none">n/a</content>
<content name="Last_updated_date" type="text">2017-07-27 
08:32:56.0000000</content>
<content name="Sort_Date" type="text" action="none">1501133576</content>
<content name="Knowledge_item_name" type="text" name- 
original="Case_title">Unable to write Statistics when Gatherer</content>
<content name="instacne_ID" type="text" name- 
original="Instance_ID">f52ec8d04f5c43000aa036e18110c771</content>
<content name="Business_line" type="text" name- 
original="business_line">APS</content>
 </document>
</vce>
```

my goal is to transform this `XML` to empty if certain content is equal to a certain value.
for example `if content[@name = 'Knowledge_item_ID'] /text() = '300384- 040406'` than I want to empty the values of all the other contents, meaning:

```
<vce>
 <document>
   <content/>
   <content/> 
      .
      .
      .
   <content/>
 <document/>
</vce>
```

I'm pretty new to `XSLT` and am not sure how to make the empty all the nodes if the inner node has a certain value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note your XML is not well-formed, as you have used `&` in some attributes which need to be escaped...

```
<document url="https://amdocssandbox.service-now.com/aps/?table=sn_customerservice_aps_and_optima_cases&amp;sys_id=300384-040406&amp;id=aps_case_details" ...
```

(You also have line-breaks in your attribute names, which also causes issues)

But assuming you have well-formed XML, the expression you want is this

```
<xsl:template match="*[content[@name='Knowledge_item_ID'] = '300384-040406']/content">
```

Within in this template you would just create an empty `content` element.

This would be used in conjunction with the identity template to handle any other elements

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[content[@name='Knowledge_item_ID'] = '300384-040406']/content">
    <xsl:copy />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMw

Edit: In answer to your comment, if you actually want to remove the `document` elements, and leave only `vce` elements, try this instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="document[content[@name='Knowledge_item_ID'] = '300384-040406']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this solution, the first template is the identity template, which just copies across nodes unchanged.

The second template, which has a higher priority, and so will be matched first, will match `document` elements that contain `content` elements where "Knowledge_item_ID" equals "300384-040406". In this case, the template does nothing, and so won't copy the `document` element to the output.

If a `document` element does not have a matching "Knowledge_item_ID" then only the identity template will match it, and then copy it unchanged.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMw/1

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your answer.
I'm using this in Watson Explorer application (by IBM). 
the XML is the XML that is created by the application and I'm trying to convert it (it is an application which creates search engines and I want to empty the content in order to make sure some documents are not indexed.)

the following code empties all of the documents:
    <xsl:template match="/">  <vce>    <xsl:apply-templates select="/document" />  
    </vce></xsl:template>

and this code changes, for example, the value of content (attached in the next comments - no more space)

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//content[@name='Knowledge_item_ID']/text()[.='300384-040406 ']">new value</xsl:template>

i just can't combine them - i want hat if the template match than it will empty the vce

Comment: unfortunately the code you provided doesn't work in the application

Comment: You may need to edit your question to show a better example of your XML and expected input, as I am now not sure what your actual requirement is. Sorry.

Comment: hi TIM I was misleading you the requested output is only
<vce/> - meaning i need to delete the other tags

Comment: you you please elaborate on the solution you provided